# Разное поведение для статических атрибутов класса

Tags: python, pandas, классы, атрибуты

Почему по разному ведет себя статический атрибут класса в случаи с pandas? Возможно, что я заморачиваюсь конечно, но такое поведение не дает покоя.

```
class test:
    table=[]
    def __init__(self,count):
        self.a=count

    def changer(self):
        self.a+=1
        self.table=self.table.append(self.a)

class test2:
    table=pd.DataFrame()
    def __init__(self,count):
        self.a=count

    def changer(self):
        self.a+=1
        self.table=self.table.append({self.a:self.a},ignore_index=True)

for i in [1,2,3]:
    i=test(i)
    i.changer()
print(test.table)
    
for i in [5,6,7]:
    i=test2(i)
    i.changer()
print(test2.table)
```

в первом случаи статический атрибут список. и print(test.table)>>>[2,3,4]
во втором случаи объект pandas, в который построчно добавляем строки, но результат пустой dataframe. Чем вызвано такое странное поведение и как лучше это обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы добавите `print(self.table)` в оба метода `changer`, то вас будет ожидать некоторый сюрприз. Вдруг выяснится, что `self.table` после присвоения ей нового значения - это совсем отдельная сущность от `class.table` и у первого класса в `self.table` после присваивания будет вообще значение `None`.

Однако при этом `self.table.append` в случае списка пополняет `class.table`, что логично - ведь для списка `.append` работает `in place` и добавляет значения именно в тот список, на который указывает ссылка `class.table`, а вот с `Pandas` такой трюк не пройдёт, потому что там `table.append` не добавляет ничего в имеющуюся таблицу, а создаёт новую.

Но я могу вам подсказать вариант, который будет работать в случае с `Pandas`. Для этого надо поменять инициализацию класса `test2` и метод `changer`:

```
class test2:
    table=pd.DataFrame({0: [0]}) # делаем одну колонку с одним значением
    def __init__(self,count):
        self.a=count

    def changer(self):
        self.a+=1
        self.table[self.a] = self.a # пишем новое значение в исходный DataFrame
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 3, 4]
   0  6  7  8
0  0  6  7  8
```

Хотя вру, можно даже не менять инициализацию, а сделать такое присвоение в changer:

```
    def changer(self):
        self.a+=1
        self.table.loc[0, self.a] = self.a
```

Но результат при этом будет `float`:

```
[2, 3, 4]
     6    7    8
0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```